# XML Sitemap Generator can't notify google and bing

Tags: plugins, errors, seo, google-search

I am using wordpress Version 2.9.2 and XML Sitemap Generator 3.2.3

I have registered with Google Webmaster Tools.

But I get an error while notifying to Google and I really don't know what it means.

Heres a screenshot :

[image]

And when I click on view result it show me the following message:

```
Ping Test

Trying to ping: http://www.google.com/webmasters/sitemaps/ping?sitemap=http%3A%2F%2Fsearock.bplaced.net%2Fsitemap.xml.gz. The sections below should give you an idea whats going on.
Errors, Warnings, Notices:
WP_DEBUG was set to false somewhere before. You might not see all debug information until you remove this declaration!
Result (text only):
Result (HTML):
```

If I want to debug the error where can I find WP_DEBUG ? Can someone tell me what's wrong here.

Note : I have completed Google Webmaster verification process.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`WP_DEBUG`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Debug) is a constant which you can define in `wp-config.php` to disable hiding of PHP errors and notices.

Add `define('WP_DEBUG', true);` to your config file to enable it.

Just remember to never leave it on for long on a live blog.

Since all pings fail this is likely not an issue with specific sitemap service, but with ping process itself. I think it might be HTTP requests failing for some reason, but there is no way to tell definitively from information you provided so far.

Comment: +1 what additional details do you need ? Do you want the error message after setting WP_DEBUG to true?

Comment: @Searock yep, that would make sense for starters. Also if this is HTTP-related you can try [Core Control](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/core-control/) plugin that has great functionality for testing and logging HTTP requests in WP.

Answer (score 1):

Try to Check your .htacces, and reset to wordpress default .htaccess;

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

and go to plugin to REBUILD Your Sitemap manually...., well at least IT WORKS FOR ME... !